# WP link picks up UTM tags from FB campaign and puts the UTM on the URLs, creating a redirecting loop

Tags: wordpress, redirect, google-analytics, redirect-loop, facebook-ads

A few weeks ago my website started out of nowhere to redirect to a Facebook campaign (I haven't made any major changes when it comes to my plugins - using the same ones since November and the campaigns are running since September). Because of this I keep on receiving a 'Too many redirects error' every few minutes/hours.

When I enter my website URL (https://example.org), I end up on something that looks like this: https://example.org/?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Lookalilke%20Clienti%2FEngaged&utm_content=Eggplant%20CA&fbclid=IwAR0KlymGRTPvafRhthSIoQt8JHc6bQ_4UWcgMB-zCZ1_PT-OgFXXwy51qBQ_aem_AfEQvjgrHGueFbDdplud55qRbdyYLVhw5FQsQVLYy6fEE3vYIdKqA13JeDiOc0cciBMBO1D_BpB1XA_odGCExeqbaafBoBnnX8uWMcBf6zzpXQ

At the beginning I thought that it might be a plugin's fault. I deleted the plugin I was using for Google Analytics and installed another one. Unfortunately, the problem persisted. It only disappeared after I deleted the campaign it was redirecting to (it was always the same campaign).

After one week of having no redirects, I notice that it started again, this time it picks up the UTM tags of a different campaign...

Has anyone encountered this before? Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Hi, just want to add that I have to same problem. Have not found the reason nor a solution yet unfortunately.

Comment: Have you found a solution already?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The only thing that seems to work for me is deleting the Facebook campaigns. So far, I had to delete two of them...

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing this same issue now on a client's website, but I don't have access to their Facebook campaigns. I was able to temporarily correct the issue by modifying the wp-config.php file to auto-clear cookies on each visit. Added the following code here:

```
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

Unfortunately, the issue has now re-appeared. Looks like i will have to ask client to delete the FB campaign unless someone else has come up with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem as well and I found the likely issue is with the SiteGround Optimizer Plugin causing this 301 redirect loop via caching for random visitors when an entirely different user visits the site with a UTM tag. Could you confirm or deny whether you are using SiteGround Optimizer as well?

Here's a thread at WordPress.org about the issue: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/301-redirect-36/

Answer (score 0):

I am using LiteSpeed Cache and the same issues occur

UTM tags, redirect loop. I believe it may have something todo with Cloudflare although I have seen it occur on proxied/unproxied

I enabled ignore query strings on both CF/LSC but it did not help

Think it has something to do with the SSL cert as well, redirecting from http/https

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).